# How do I get the asm variable value in C language?

Tags: c, cortex-m, firmware

Now I'm trying to understand the CM3 firmware code.
But especially I found some of the code is made by asm code as the below,
[asm code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqvnd.png)

```
// Uart string output 
void UartPuts(unsigned char * mytext)
{
  unsigned char CurrChar;
  do {
    CurrChar = *mytext;
    if (CurrChar != (char) 0x0) {
      UartPutc(CurrChar);  // Normal data
      }
    *mytext++;
  } while (CurrChar != 0); 
  return;
}   
#if defined ( __CC_ARM   )
/* ARM RVDS or Keil MDK */
__asm void FlashLoader_ASM(void)
{
   MOVS  R0,#0
   LDR   R1,[R0]     ; Get initial MSP value
   MOV   SP, R1
   LDR   R1,[R0, #4] ; Get initial PC value
   BX    R1
}
```

and I want to print MSP value and PC value out by using UartPuts function.

Would you please guide me how am I supposed to do to print it out ?

Comment: Please don't post images of code.  When you asked your question, the instructions explicitly said "Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly."

Comment: read address 0x00000000 and 0x00000004, no assembly language 'required' and then you can do whatever you want with the value read, print it or whatever.

Comment: What is your real question are you having problems reading a word at an address?  Are you having problems taking the value read and converting it into ascii to print it out?  Having problems writing an assembly language function that can be called and useful from C?  Please show what you have so far and what you are trying to get it to do.

Comment: @old_timer how exactly read address 0x0 and 0x04 ? that is inline asssembly language in C code. means we can't use directly inline assembly language's variable to C language.

Comment: assembly language does not have variables, that is a high level language concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way (gas syntax):

```
.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr

extern unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
unsigned int x;
...
x = GET32(0x00000000);
...
x = GET32(0x00000004);
```

another way no asm required:

```
#define ZERO (*((volatile unsigned int *)0x00000000))
#define FOUR (*((volatile unsigned int *)0x00000004))
...
unsigned int x;
...
x = ZERO;
...
x = FOUR;
```

Can use uint32_t instead of unsigned int if you have a stdint.h or equivalent.  (will result in unsigned int for gcc and clang/llvm).

derived from your code/syntax

```
__asm uint32_t read_zero(void)
{
   MOVS  R0,#0
   LDR   R0,[R0]
   BX LR
}

__asm uint32_t read_four(void)
{
   MOVS  R0,#4
   LDR   R0,[R0]
   BX LR
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small caveat. If you attempt to read from address 0x0 using 'C', there is a high chance that you will run into a compile time null pointer trap, since your initial stack pointer pointer is defined in C as not being a legal pointer.

Thus, depending on the compiler (pre gcc 4.9.3 will not do this), you may see a completely unexpected `undef_opcode` in the assembled output. There is no 'clean' way to read from address 0 in C, but using pointer arithmatic should work (unless you enable runtime null pointer checks).